# how to create a textfile in mysql

Tags: mysql

am trying in mysql to print two table query result in one text file
Note :employee table has 6 column..

```
 select * from employee union
 select cardnum,txndate,terminalid,txnamount from users INTO OUTFILE 'E:/antonyfile.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

its showing "used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"..is there any solution for this..atleast please tell me how to append or add a string into already exists text file in mysql.

Comment: Mihai, you have understand Union keyword logic before running your query. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx and few basic points :- "The number of columns appears in the corresponding SELECT statements must be equal."
"The columns appear in  the corresponding positions of each SELECT statement must have the same data type or, at least, convertible data type."

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the column names not `select *` and add nulll for the 2 columns which are not in user

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6 from employee union
 select cardnum,txndate,terminalid,txnamount,null,null from users INTO OUTFILE 'E:/antonyfile.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: thank you i got it...and please help me one thing..how to delete a file using mysql query..is there any option .. or how to delete a folder ...please help me out from this issue

Comment: @AntonytintoJ I do not think that is is possible in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Since employee table has 6 columns than sub-select "select * from emplyee" has also 6 columns. But "select cardnum,txndate,terminalid,txnamount from users" have only 4 columns that is not valid union operation.

Is there any relation between tables emploee and users?

Probably you can write

```
select e.*, u.cardnum,u.txndate,i.terminalid,u.txnamount 
 from employee e 
 left join users u on **e.!!user_id!! = u.!!user_Id!!**
union
select e.*, u.cardnum,u.txndate,i.terminalid,u.txnamount 
 from employee e 
 right join users u on **e.!!user_id!! = u.!!user_Id!!**

INTO OUTFILE 'E:/antonyfile.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
```